# Discrepancy in Definition of Discriminant of Binary Quadratic Form

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Given a quadratic form, the discriminant is usually defined as the determinant of the associated symmetric matrix. However, I've seen a number of authors define the discriminant associated to the binary quadratic form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ to be $4ac - b^2$, when the determinant of the associated symmetric matrix is $ac - b^2/4$. Is there any good reason to take one definition of discriminant over the other?

Comment: no.   It's the same thing.   https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: @individ My apologies, but I don't understand what the post you linked is trying to establish in relation to my question. Could you please explain?

Comment: It is a problem of note to some Pell equation. The note gives a lot of different equivalent forms. It can have very diverse forms. You can imagine it in different ways, but it's all equivalent to each other.

Comment: Can you elaborate (in an answer perhaps) on why some authors use b^2-4ac and others (e.g. Apostol) use 4ac-b^2? Or at least, why they are "equivalent" ?